# docker compose with zipkin and elasticsearch not working : 2024-02-10 19:35:30 24/02/11 03:35:30 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200]

Tags: docker, apache-spark, elasticsearch, docker-compose, zipkin

`30 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting... 2024-02-10 19:35:30 Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only`

i get this error.

`version: '2'

services:
zipkin:
image: openzipkin/zipkin-slim
container_name: zipkin
environment:
- STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch
- ES_HOSTS=elasticsearch:9200
ports:
- 9411:9411
networks:
- zipkin_network

storage:
image: openzipkin/zipkin-elasticsearch6
container_name: elasticsearch
ports:
- 9200:9200
environment:
- ES_HTTP_LOGGING=BODY
networks:
- zipkin_network

dependencies:
image: openzipkin/zipkin-dependencies:2
environment:
- STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch
- ES_HOSTS=elasticsearch:9200
networks:
- zipkin_network

networks:
zipkin_network:
driver: bridge
`

this is my docker compose i tried typing - ES_HOSTS=elasticsearch:9200 to localhost:9200 but nothin, I tried to run it without bridging the network but still the same error, also tried different versions of elasticsearch and zipkin deps.
any help would be appreciated thanks in advance